# How do I read lines from a txt file and add each line to a type LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list, bluej

So basically the program calls to use a class type LinkedList to store lines from a text file. Course is a separate class I have so that is the type of LinkedList I'm using. Here is the txt file the program is reading from

```
CPSC141 Computer_Organization   3   D
CPSC130 Computer_ProgrammingI   3   B
Math140 Calculus_I  4   E
CPSC232 Assembler_Languages 3   B
CPSC131 Computer_ProgramingII 3 A
Math141 Calculus_II 4   B
```

Here is my code

```
File inFile = new File("courses.txt");
    Scanner f = new Scanner(inFile);
    while (f.hasNextLine())
    {
        Courses.add(f);
    }
    f.close();
```

The problem is I get an error message that says this

```
method.java.util.Collection.add(Course) is not applicable;
(argument mismatch; java.util.Scanner cannot be converted to Course);
```

I don't know how to convert the string from the txt file to type Course (my separate class)

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 you can simply use:

```
List<String> yourList = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("courses.txt"));
```

Comment: It is not LinkedList.

Comment: Surely. But it is preferable to use interface link

Comment: Yes but I would I implement that with my LinkedList<Course>

Comment: If you need exactly LinkedList, you may use
`LinkedList<String> yourList = new LinkedList<String>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("courses.txt")));`
but IMHO it is overkill

Answer (score 0):

`f` is a `Scanner` instance. Change it to the line that it read in following line.

```
//from
Courses.add(f);
//To
Courses.add(f.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the variable f is a Scanner instance. You can either convert it to a string with String.valueOf or toString() methods, or read the entire line as a string.